# Turn Pandas DataFrame to boolean list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, series

I would like to turn a Series of frequencies that I initialised in a loop over csv-files like so

```
setfreq_df = pd.concat([setfreq_df, EIS_csv['SetFreq'].astype(float)], ignore_index = True)
```

into a single boolean value or a boolean list. I need to check whether the data is corrupted, right now specifically whether all the frequencies are below 7000. I tried this in the following way:

```
bool_list = [(y < 7000) for y in setfreq_df]
```

which produces the output

```
[True]
```

I don't know how to interpret this result as I was expecting a list as long as the column of the DataFrame. Also I tried this with 6000 and it returned the same result even though I know there are frequencies of 6,5 kHz in the csv.

What went wrong here and how could I get it done? Thank you

Comment: Use `setfreq_df[setfreq_df < 7000]`

Comment: @jezrael This is not an answer to my question. How about you read it before you close it down. Your answer selects all rows that are below 7kHz. I don't want to select a row from the original frame. I want a boolean list or series of bools.

Comment: Ok, so need `setfreq_df < 7000` ?

Comment: Ok that is wierd but yes exactly what I wanted, thank you.
Can you reference me to a post where that syntax is explained?

Comment: hmm, I think here [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: compare column by some value, it is used mainly for filtering in boolean indexing. But is possible mask use like `setfreq_df < 7000`

Comment: That is about selecting rows via boolean conditions. That is not what I meant which is why I did not think the post was a duplicate. With your second answer you are creating a new df, not just selecting rows. Does this work for functions in general? like for a function g: 

df_2 =  g(df_1)

This is the syntax I meant.

Comment: Sorry, not understand. So need answer `setfreq_df < 7000` or dupe for `setfreq_df < 7000` ?

Comment: Does 
```new_df = g(setfreq_df)```
work for general functions g() or only for boolean conditions (like ```g(x) : return (x < 7000)```)?

Comment: It is call for data of all column, so working like `mask = setfreq_df < 7000` (if understand well)